# Passing by Pointers vs Passing by reference

Tags: c++, pointers

I have understood the fact that a calling a function by reference can be done in two ways either passing the variable by reference or passing the variable by pointers. 
But now I am stuck at the o/p difference of it

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void test(int *a)
{

    cout<<&a<<"  ";
}
int main()
{
   int a[4]={5,3,8,2};
   for(int i=0;i<4;++i)
   {
        test(&a[i]);    
   }
    return 0;
}
```

This gives me the same address location but shouldn't it be different as we are passing &a[i]--> the address of ith element every time it is called which is received by the pointer a but I get the same address every time which is the starting address of the array 
while if I modify the function call somewhat I get the expected o/p 
which is from the below code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void test(int &a)
{

    cout<<&a<<"  ";
}
int main()
{
   int a[4]={5,3,8,2};
   for(int i=0;i<4;++i)
   {
        test(a[i]);    
   }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first example, you are printing the address of the pointer itself. That is a local variable of your function. If you print out the address of the thing it points too, you will see different addresses:

```
cout<< &(*a) << "  ";
cout << a << "  ";    // same as above
```

In your second example, the reference refers to the argument passed to the function. Getting the address of a reference is the same as getting the address of the object it refers to, because a reference is just an alias for an object.

Comment: To print out the address of the thing it points to, I would use `cout << a;`